# Taylor series expansion of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta x(x+1)}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find the taylor series expansion about $0$ (maclaurin series) of $$x \rightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta x(x+1)}} \text{ with } \beta \in \mathbb{R}^{+*}$$

I've tried using the taylor series expansion of $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-X}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}4^{-n}{2n \choose n}X^n \text{ }\text{ }\text{ }\text{ with } \text{ } X=\beta x(x+1)$$

But I can't turn it into a power series because of the $(x+1)^n$...

I've also tried to derive $$\frac{1}{n!}\cdot\frac{\text{d}^n}{\text{d}x^n}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta x(x+1)}}\right)_{x=0}$$
But no results so far...

**Edit** : with a more powerful method, I found that, if we call $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ the coefficients of the taylor series expansion $\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\beta x(x+1)}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^n\right)$, the sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is then defined by :
$$\forall n\geq3, \text{} na_n=\beta\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)a_{n-1}+\beta\left(n-1\right)a_{n-2}$$
$$\text{with }\text{ }a_1 = \frac{\beta}{2} \text{ , } a_2 = \frac{3}{8}\beta^2+\frac{1}{2}\beta$$

It's definitely a step forward, but I don't know how to proceed from there. Is there a way to handle sequences that are defined by such a way ?

Answer (score 3):

I would set $y = \beta x(x+1)$. With that:
\begin{align}
\frac1{\sqrt{1 - y}}
   &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 4^{-n} \binom{2n}{n} y^n\\
   &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 4^{-n} \binom{2n}{n} \beta^n x^n (x+1)^n\\
   &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n} 4^{-n} \binom{2n}{n} \binom{n}{k} \beta^n x^n x^k \\
   &= \sum_{m=0}^{\infty} a_m x^m
\end{align}
where $m = n + k$, so $a_m = \sum_{n=0}^{m} 4^{-n}\binom{2n}{n}\binom{n}{m-n} \beta^n$.

$a_m$ is simply an number which you can calculate doing some sums and products. For $m = 0, \dots, 3$ the $a_m$ are $1,\frac{\beta }{2},\frac{1}{8} \beta  (3 \beta +4),\frac{1}{16} \beta ^2 (5
   \beta +12)$.

Mathematica "simplifies" $a_m$ to 
$$
a_m = 4^{-m} \binom{2 m}{m} \beta ^m \,
   _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{m}{2},-\frac{m}{2};\frac{1}{2}-m;-\frac{4}{\beta
   }\right)
$$
where $_2F_1$ denotes the [Hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function).

Comment: Well actually, after numerical simulation, your numerical values don't seem to work...

Comment: @HarmonicSun Yes, I had forgotten to include $\beta$. The values are not as pretty now but you can still easily calculate them.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot !
Additionaly, do you think that based on my edit on my initial question, one can derive a prettier closed form for the $a_m$ ?

Comment: I might be picky but, in your formula for $a_m$, ${n \choose m-n}$ is not defined for, say, n=0... Or do we take it a 0 conventionaly ?

Comment: @HarmonicSun Yes, the Binomial coefficient $\binom{a}{b}$ is understood to be zero when $a < b$ (and $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$).

Answer (score 1):

By the Faa di Bruno formula and some properties of the partial Bell polynomials, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{\operatorname{d}^n}{\operatorname{d}x^n}\biggl[\frac1{\sqrt{1-\beta x(x+1)}\,}\biggr]
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_k\frac1{[1-\beta x(x+1)]^{1/2+k}} B_{n,k}(-\beta(2x+1), -2\beta,0,\dotsc,0)\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_k\frac1{[1-\beta x(x+1)]^{1/2+k}} (-2\beta)^kB_{n,k}\biggl(x+\frac12, 1,0,\dotsc,0\biggr)\\
&\to\sum_{k=0}^n\biggl\langle-\frac12\biggr\rangle_k (-2\beta)^kB_{n,k}\biggl(\frac12, 1,0,\dotsc,0\biggr),\quad x\to0\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\frac{(2k-1)!!}{2^k} (-2\beta)^k \frac{1}{2^{n-k}}\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}\frac1{2^{2k-n}}\\
&=n!\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} \binom{k}{n-k} \beta^k,
\end{align}
where we used
\begin{equation}\label{Bell-x-1-0-eq}
B_{n,k}(x,1,0,\dotsc,0)
=\frac{1}{2^{n-k}}\frac{n!}{k!}\binom{k}{n-k}x^{2k-n}.
\end{equation}
Consequently, we conclude
\begin{equation}
\frac1{\sqrt{1-\beta x(x+1)}\,}
=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(2k-1)!!}{(2k)!!} \binom{k}{n-k} \beta^k\Biggr]x^n.
\end{equation}

References

1. F. Qi and B.-N. Guo, *Explicit formulas for special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind and for the Euler numbers and polynomials*, Mediterr. J. Math. **14** (2017), no. 3, Art. 140, 14 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1007/s00009-017-0939-1.
2. F. Qi and M.-M. Zheng, *Explicit expressions for a family of the Bell polynomials and applications*, Appl. Math. Comput. **258** (2015), 597--607; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.02.027.
3. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.

Comment: Is it possible to do it via Gegenbauer polynomials?